Unit ball as norm closure of the convex hull of extreme points in $\ell_\infty(X)$
Let $\ell_\infty(X)$ be the Banach space of bounded sequences taking values in a Banach space $X$, endowed with the supremum norm. Let $B_{\ell_\infty(X)}$ be the closed unit ball of $\ell_\infty(X)$.
If $X=\mathbb{R}$ then $B_{\ell_\infty(X)}$ (i.e., the closed unit ball of $\ell_\infty$) is the norm closure of the convex hull of its extreme points (this follows by an old article by Goodner (1964).)

Question 1. Is it true that if $X$ is a finite-dimensional Banach space then $B_{\ell_\infty(X)}=\overline{\mathrm{co}}(\mathrm{Ext}(B_{\ell_\infty(X)}))$?


Question 2. Is it true that there exists an infinite-dimensional Banach space $X$ such that $B_{\ell_\infty(X)}\neq \overline{\mathrm{co}}(\mathrm{Ext}(B_{\ell_\infty(X)}))$?

As suggested by S Argyros in the comments, if $(x_n)_n \in \mathrm{Ext}(\ell_\infty(X))$, then $x_n \in \mathrm{Ext}(B_X)$ for each $n$. Hence, if $\mathrm{Ext}(B_X)=\emptyset$ (e.g. if $X=c_0$) then we obtain a positive answer to Question 2. A refinement of Question 2 suggested by S Argyros follows:

Question 3. Let $X$ be a Banach space such that $B_{X}= \overline{\mathrm{co}}(\mathrm{Ext}(B_{X}))$. Is it true that $B_{\ell_\infty(X)}= \overline{\mathrm{co}}(\mathrm{Ext}(B_{\ell_\infty(X)}))$? (For instance, does it hold for $X=\ell_1$?)


In your second paragraph you seem to be assuming that $\ell_\infty(X)$ is a dual space since you talk about it having a weak$^\ast$ topology, but you make no related assumptions on $X$ in the first paragraph. But if your question is really about when the unit ball of $\ell_\infty(X)$ is the norm closed convex hull of its extreme points, then you can probably just phrase the question that way and omit any reference to weak$^\ast$ topologies.

If $(x_n)n$ is an extreme point of the unit ball of $\ell\infty (X)$ then each $x_n$ is an extreme point of the unit ball of $X$. Thus if the ball of $X$ does not have extreme points, for example as the ball of $c_0$, then also there is no extreme point in $\ell_\infty(X) $.

The following is a refinement of the original question.Assume that for  a Banach space $X$ holds $B_X=\overline{co}(ext(B_X)$. Is this property remains valid for the unit ball of $\ell_\infty(X)$?

For $X$ a Banach space we have that
\begin{equation}
Ext(B_{{\ell_\infty}(X)}) =\Big \{(x_n)_n : x_n \in Ext(B_X)\Big\}
\end{equation}
In the case of $\ell_\infty $ we know that $B_{\ell_\infty} = \overline{co} Ext(B_{\ell_\infty})$ where the closure is taken in the norm of  $\ell_\infty $.If we analyse the proof we conclude that the critical property  we use is that every  $ x\in B_ R$ is the convex combination of at most two extreme points.Therefore whenever we have a similar property for a Banach space $X$ then we also have that $B_{{\ell_\infty} (X)}
= \overline{co} Ext(B_{{{\ell_\infty }(X)}})$.  In particular for $X$ a Banach space we set
\begin{equation}
 \alpha(X)  = min\Big\{ k:\forall x\in B_X,\, x=\sum_{i\leq k }a_ix_i,\, \{x_i\}_i\subset Ext(B_X),\,a_i\geq 0 \, \sum_{i \leq k}a_i =1 \Big \}
\end{equation}
We are interested for $X$ for which $\alpha(X)< \infty$.
This property occurs whenever $X$ is of finite dimension as well as in  spaces with a strictly convex norm.
Theorem: Let $X$ be a Banach space with  $\alpha(X) < \infty$.Then
$B_{{\ell_\infty}(X)} = \overline{co} Ext(B_{{\ell_\infty}(X)})$.
The proof is based on the following two steps.
Step 1 : We start with the next definition.
Definition : A $z\in B_{{\ell_\infty}(X)}$ is a $k$ -simple function if there exist $X_1, \dots, X_k \in Ext(B_{{\ell_\infty}(X)})$ , $A_1,\dots, A_m \in S_{\ell_1^{+}(k)}$ and a partition $\{G_p\}_{p\leq m}$ of $N$
such that for every $1\leq p\leq m$ and every $n\in G_p$ we have
$z(n) = < A_p, (X_i(n))_{i=1}^k> $
Lemma 1: Assume that $\alpha(X) = k< \infty $. Then for every $y \in B_{{\ell_\infty}(X)}$ and $\epsilon>0 $ there exists a $k$ -simple function $z$ such that $\|y-z\| < \epsilon$.
Step 2:
Lemma 2 : Every $k$-simple function $z$ is a convex combination of elements of $Ext(B_{{\ell_\infty}(X)})$.
Proof We consider the element $w$ in $\ell_\infty^m( \ell_1^k)$ defined as $w( p, i )= A_p(i)$. Then $\|w\| \leq 1$ and hence it is a convex combination of elements of $Ext(B_{\ell_\infty^m( \ell_1^k)})$This convex combination induces a convex combination of
elements of $Ext(B_{{\ell_\infty}(X)})$ equal to $z$.
Remark : A slight modification of the definition of $\alpha(X) < \infty$ leads to a complete characterisation of the spaces $X$ satisfying $B_{{\ell_\infty}(X)} = \overline{co} Ext(B_{{\ell_\infty}(X)})$.
Definition Let $X$ be a Banach space and $\epsilon >0$. We say that $(\alpha(X), \epsilon) \leq k$ if the $k$- convex combinations of the extreme points of $B_X$ are $\epsilon $ dense in the $B_X$.
We say that $\alpha (X) $ is $\epsilon$ - bounded  if  $(\alpha(X), \epsilon) < \infty$ for every $\epsilon>0$.
Theorem Let $X$ be a Banach space. The following are equivalent.
(i) $\alpha(X)$ is $\epsilon$- bounded.
(ii)  $B_{{\ell_\infty}(X)} = \overline{co} Ext(B_{{\ell_\infty}(X)})$.
In the case of the space $Y = \ell_\infty (\ell_1)$ the answer is negative.
Indeed we set $x_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^ne_i$ then for every $y\in coExt(B_Y)$ we have $\|y - (x_n)_n \| \geq 1$.

Thank you for the answer! I didn't get why $\alpha(X)<\infty$ is sufficient: if $(x_n) \in B_{\ell_\infty(X)}$ and each $x_n$ is an average of at most $\alpha(X)$ extreme points of $B_X$ (which may vary depending on $n$), how can we approximate $(x_n)$ with an average of some extreme points in $B_{\ell_\infty(X)}$?

I agree that it is not obvious. Probably tomorrow  I will try to add some more details of the proof.
